exclude values from a sum total when not within parameter selection in SSRS
I have a report that shows each row with a sum broken out by line item. I.E.:



Category
Field
Total Count




Cat A
A
50


Cat A
B
100


Cat B
C
50


Cat B
D
25



Cat A Total:  150
Cat B Total:  75
All Total:    225
Each row total is listed as this:
sum(iif(Fields!Field.Value = "A",1,0))

so there is a total of 50 "A"s. And so forth. The total per category is
sum(iif(Fields!Category.Value = "Cat A",1,0))

Then for the total, it is
sum(iif(Fields!Category.Value = "Cat A",1,0)) + Sum(iif(Fields!Category.Value = "Cat B", 1, 0))

This all works fine. However, I have a parameter to select the field(s) needed. Is there a way to exclude the total count of a field from the totals? So if someone selects all fields in the field parameter except "A", I would want to see the following:



Category
Field
Total Count




Cat A
B
100


Cat B
C
50


Cat B
D
25



Cat A Total:  100
Cat B Total:  75
All Total:    175
Is this possible with some fancy footwork?
I did try some different steps with the row visibility settings since I do not want to show the rows that are not selected in the field parameter, but not sure how to incorporate. Here is the visibility setting at the row level:
iif(
    InStr(Join(Parameters!Category.Label,","),"Cat A") > 0
    and InStr(Join(Parameters!Field.Label,","),"A") > 0
,false,true)


The SUM expression should check both parameter and row in order to count it.
=Sum(iif(InStr(Join(Parameters!Category.Label, ","), "Cat A") > 0, 1, 0) * iif(InStr(Join(Parameters!Field.Label, ","), "A") > 0, 1, 0) * Iif(Fields!category.Value="Cat A",1,0) * Iif(Fields!field.Value="A",1,0))


For the totals of CatA, CatB and CatA + CatB you can use ReportItems expressions like the one below
=ReportItems!Textbox15.Value + ReportItems!Textbox18.Value


The final result will look like the images below (to demonstrate the totals I left all rows visible)



problem is I am not using row groups. And I really do not want to add a large list of field selections since there are twenty to thirty per category. That would end up something like = SUM(
iif (InStr(Join(Parameters!Field.Label,","), "A") > 0,1,0) +
iif (InStr(Join(Parameters!Field.Label,","), "B") > 0,1,0) +
iif (InStr(Join(Parameters!Field.Label,","), "C") > 0,1,0)) and so on...

You mean rows are statically defined?

Yep. I have the table underneath but is hidden. Then above that I have all the totals per field & category.

why the asterisk and not the word "and"?

I check all conditions and if all true you get 1. You can also use an Iif with 4 conditions combined with AND

clever, I like that. And the whole thing works like a charm. Thank you for your assistance!

Since its working, you may mark it as accepted

I tried but won't let me. Apparently, my reputation is not high enough...

I think you can even with reputation 1.  It doesn't matter, nice to know it was helpful.

@Michael_Alex The "accept" is the check mark to the left, under the vote up/down buttons. You should be able to accept answers to your own question regardless of reputation. Are you sure you're not trying to vote it up?
